# Can't get ng-repeat to list out users in object | no error msg

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

I'm in the very early staged of learning Angular. This is the first controller I've written for a Sharepoint application I'm working on. Basically when the page loads, the controller is suppose to make an ajax call to sharepoint server and return and xml will all the users on the site. I want to take that information and parse it into an object. From there I'll do stuff with it later. I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. Also, is this something I should be using a service for?

```
spApp.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.getUsers = function(){   
        $scope.userObject = [];
        $().SPServices({
            operation: "GetUserCollectionFromSite",
            completefunc: function(xData, Status) {
                users = $(xData.responseXML);
                users.find("User").each(function() {

                    userObject.push({
                        id: $(this).attr("ID"),
                        name: $(this).attr("Name"),
                        login: $(this).attr("LoginName")
                    });
                });
            }
        });
        return $scope.userObject;
    }
    $scope.getUsers();
}])


            <select id="entityDropDown">
                <option ng-repeat="user in $scope.userObject" name-id="{{$scope.userObject.id}}" data-domainName="{{$scope.userObject.login}}">{{$scope.userObject.name}}</option>
            </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using  `userObject.push` instead of `$scope.userObject.push` in your `completefunc`

Answer (score 0):

```
**$scope.userObject.push({
id: $(this).attr("ID"),
name: $(this).attr("Name"),
login: $(this).attr("LoginName")
});**
```